# How to calculate the rank of a list without pandas and numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing, ranking

i've written the following code:

```
  s = [2,1,-99,100,45,-2] 
    li=[] 

    for i in range(len(s)): 
       li.append([s[i],i]) 
       li.sort() 
       sort_index = []

    for x in li: 
       sort_index.append(x[1]) 

    print(sort_index) 

   this gives the output as :[2, 5, 1, 0, 4, 3]
```

required output : [4,3,1,6,5,2]
I need the rank such that the output is the rank of the first element of s

what are the suggested changes in my code to find the rank. And we shouldn't use numpy and pandas

Comment: Why should the output be [4,3,1,6,5,2]? By rank do you mean like rank of a matrix, or are you trying to sort the array in a different order?

Answer (score 0):

Ranking in this context appears to be in terms of sorted order.  For that purpose one can compare the position of the elements in the original list against a sorted list to get the correct answer.

Example:

```
s = [2,1,-99,100,45,-2]
sorted_s = sorted(s)
ranked_s = [
    sorted_s.index(value) + 1
    for value in s
]
print(rank)
```

Output:

```
[4, 3, 1, 6, 5, 2]
```

Comment: thank you sir, in case of tie- breaks like [2,1,-99,100,100,45,-2]. It has to return [4,3,1,6,7,5,2] instead of [4,3,1,6,6,5,2]. How to overcome this?

Comment: Try to add `set()` then. Like this: ranks = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(sorted(set(s)), 1)}